# distinct selects in lithium

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

Using Lithiums Model, how do you achieve getting a distinct result set of specific fields from a collection in MongoDB?

mongo query:

```
db.blogs.distinct('url');
```

Comment: Finally a Lithium user! But why use Mongo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to do this elegantly to my knowledge.  You can get results by working with the [Pecl MongoDB](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php) object directly. The `command` function allows you to make any call you want.

```
$db = Connections::get('default');
$blogs = $db->connection->command(array('distinct'=>'blogs', 'key'=>'url'));
```