# Lithium mongodb distinct command with conditions

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, lithium

In lithium models, I can use the `command()` to select distinct of specific field (See [distinct selects in lithium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750561/distinct-selects-in-lithium)):

```
$blogs = $self->connection->command(array('distinct'=>'blogs', 'key'=>'url'));
```

which is translated to mongodb command as:

```
db.blogs.distinct('url');
```

Now I want to add a condition on type='rumours' in my distinct query:

```
db.blogs.distinct('url', {type: 'rumours'});
```

How do I add this `{type: 'rumours'}` condition in `command()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional argument in the shell method is a "query" document, so if you follow the [distinct command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) documentation:

```
$blogs = $self->connection->command(
    array('distinct'=>'blogs', 'key'=>'url', 'query' => array( 'type' => 'rumours' ) )
);
```

So the only thing missing here is the "query" key in the command document you are sending.